# Import home-made python function in paraview

Tags: python, python-2.7, paraview

I wanted to import basic functions in the python shell included in paraview. I tried:

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/my/directory')
import hello_world
```

Got the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello_world' is not defined
```

while I have a hello_world.py in the directory …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/my/directory")

import hello_world
```